# Docker SQL Server 2017 on linux connection issue

Tags: sql-server, docker

My Docker linux SQL Server is not working today at my machine.

I am not sure if this is firewall (I have off them all), or Docker settings (as I just upgraded to the latest Docker version), or a Docker SQL Server issue (but this was working fine on the same machine earlier).

Could anyone help?

I have tried using bash,

```
 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost,8010 -U SA -P Test123!
```

Error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

The docker compose file

```html
version: '3'
services:
  mssql:
    network_mode: lsvc
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    container_name: mssql
    hostname: mssql
    volumes:
      - ./.db:/var/opt/mssql/
      - /var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./sqlinit.sql:/scripts/sqlinit.sql
    ports:
      - 8010:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Test123!
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - |
        # Launch MSSQL and send to background
        /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
        # Wait for it to be available
        echo "Waiting for MS SQL to be available"
        /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -l 30 -S mssql -h-1 -V1 -U sa -P Test123! -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT \"YAY WE ARE UP\" , @@servername"
        is_up=$$?
        while [ $$is_up -ne 0 ] ; do 
          echo -e $$(date) 
          /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -l 30 -S mssql -h-1 -V1 -U sa -P Test123! -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT \"YAY WE ARE UP\" , @@servername"
          is_up=$$?
          sleep 1 
        done
        # Run every script in /scripts
        # TODO set a flag so that this is only done once on creation, 
        #      and not every time the container runs
        #for foo in /scripts/*.sql
        /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S mssql -U sa -P Test123! -l 30 -e -i /scripts/sqlinit.sql
        #done
        # So that the container doesn't shut down, sleep this thread
        sleep infinity
```

Comment: What is this line means: `network_mode: lsvc` ?  Can you test with `host`/`bridge` or just commented out ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the mssql instance had failed to start.

Looking at your docker file when the server fail to start it runs into in infinite loop. I would advice you to limit the number of retries on the loop so you will have an indication that the server is failing on startup.
Or better consider the use of the **HEALTHCHECK** option and not the loop script 
see https://blog.couchbase.com/docker-health-check-keeping-containers-healthy/

To troubleshooting the problem try

```
docker logs <mssql-container-id>
```

if this doesn't provide enough information try connecting to the container as this was a simple machine.

```
docker exec -it <mssql-container-id> bash
```

Look for errors in  /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: this is the logs as i mentioned. nothing else.
C:\Users\tester>docker logs -f mssql Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL

Comment: docker logs will display the the output from the container’s STDOUT and STDERR. Which is your sqlcmd command output in your case. Try my second option and look for server logs

Answer (score 0):

i found the root cause, it is not due to docker mssql linux

but the latest Docker Desktop Community 2.2.0.0

after uninstall it then downgrade to old version, Docker Desktop Community 2.1.0.5.

it is working now, connect to mssql success.

not sure what is new in latest docker desktop, anyway...i will use old version now.

also one important point to take note, the ".db" folder (windows path where the yml file reside), must deleted before build the docker image.